# React.js and ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, reactjs

I've just explored react.js and I think it's great, but I have a problem.
Do you have any idea how to render an extjs layout using React.js?

I know that react.js is designed to create `components`, not the whole layout. So I think that I need to make them relative (link action between components like button changes value of some div using text from other input - component?)

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2):

propagate the change up to the first common ancestor which keeps the value in its `state` and the component that uses the value get it sent in via its `props`

i.e

```
ColorChangeButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button 
                  onClick={this.props.onChangeColor}
                  className={this.props.color} />

    }
});

ColoredDiv = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div className={this.props.color} />
    }
});

Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { color:"blue" }
    },
    onChangeColor: function() {
        this.setState({color:"red"})
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <section>
            <ColorChangeButton 
                color={this.state.color} 
                onChangeColor={this.onChangeColor} />
            <ColoredDiv color={this.state.color} />
          </section>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: For future readers: If you're building a big app, instead of propagating, you should take a look into the Flux application structure with centralized states.